# How to get the newest record for every user using spring data mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am struggling with a mongo query. I need to find a collection of  documents in single query. The collection should contain document with newest date (field `createdAt`) for every user in single query.

There is a test case in Spock to demonstrate what I am trying to acheive:

```
def 'should filter the newest location for every user'() {
    given:
        List locationsInDb = [
            buildLocation(USERNAME_1, '2017-02-03T10:37:30.00Z'),
            buildLocation(USERNAME_1, '2017-03-04T10:37:30.00Z'),
            buildLocation(USERNAME_2, '2017-02-05T10:37:30.00Z'),
            buildLocation(USERNAME_2, '2017-03-06T10:37:30.00Z')
        ]
        insertToMongo(locationsInDb)
    when:
        List filteredLocations = locationRepository.findLastForEveryUser()
    then:
        filteredLocations == [locationsInDb.get(1), locationsInDb.get(3)]
}
```

I found that distinct methods are a part of `2.1.0.M1` version so they are not available yet.

I was also trying with `@Query` annotation but the documentation (link below) does not specify how to create a query like mine.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e3309

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no means to express the query you are looking for via a derived query in Spring Data, nor using the MongoDB native [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/). [Distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) as well will not do the job as it just extracts distinct values of a single field into an array.

Please consider using an [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). Spring Data specifics can be found in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).